# How to make Firebase data readable by the public?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-security

Currently creating a note-taking app and I would like to add sharing functionality in it. I would like to enable the users to share a note that is private by default to other users.

I'm a noob, so I am not quite sure how to achieve this, but what I have in my mind right now is to programmatically change the read security rule of the note that will be shared from `auth.uid == $uid` to `true` and then generate a link to that note for the user to share so that everyone can view it. But I believe this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a whitelist for a shared note.

```
{
   "notes": {
      "0": {
         "text": "I like taking notes.",
         "uid": "user_1"
      }
   },
   "sharedNotes": {
      "0": {
         "user_1": true,
         "user_2": true
      }
   }
}
```

Then in your rules you can validate that a user must exist in `/sharedNotes` for the read to succeed.

```
{
   "rules": {
      "notes": {
         "$noteId": {
            ".read": "data.root().child('sharedNotes').child($noteId).child(auth.uid).exists()"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Let's break down this rule:

```
data.root().child('sharedNotes').child($noteId).child(auth.uid).exists()
```

Go to the root, go the the `/sharedNotes` path, find the note from the `$noteId`, and then see if the current user (`auth.uid`) exists in the whitelist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but all other users must be able to view the note. If I use this approach, the user should enter which users can read the note, which is bad if the user wants to share the note to hundreds of people.

Comment: Thank you can give them access to a shareable link, and simply make the rule `".read": true`